# /usr/bin/copycat: Line 77: unexpected end of file?

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, scripting, terminal

I am getting that error on a bash script I am making for Cydia. However my file ends at like 76.

This is my first actual script so I am just kind of messing around, but would like to know the error.

Thanks!

P.S: I am coding this in gedit in Ubuntu 13.10

<strike>http://pastebin.com/pj4pBDwB</strike>

```
#!/bin/bash

#Say Hello
#Check if they need help
if [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
        echo
        echo "Usage: copycat <message>"
        echo " --exit | Exit the script."
        echo "CopyCat is a very simple script I have made for "
        echo "practice & entertainment."
        echo
        exit 0
else
        echo "===============/\===============/\==============="
        echo "Hey, "$USER". I'm CopyCat! :) I have a tendency of "
        echo "copying people..."
        echo "Remember, at any time you can exit the script by "
        echo "typing copycat --exit"
        echo
fi


#Teaser
function tease(){
        i=0
        sleep 0.2
        case "$i" in

        '0')
        echo "Teehee"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        ;;

        '1')
        echo "Your smart"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        ;;
        '2')
        echo "LOL Fool"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        ;;
        '3')
        echo "Isn't this getting old?"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        ;;
        '4')
        echo "Outta show off your brains, here!"
        i=0
esac
}

#Copy them
RUN=true
i=0
echo "CopyCat: Let's Chat!"
read ans
if [ "$ans" != "--exit" ]; then
        while [ RUN=true ]; do
                i= `expr $i + 1`
                read ans
                sleep 0.5
                echo "CopyCat: "$ans""
                tease
                echo

                if [ $i -e 4 ]; then
                        echo "CopyCat: I am tired.. I am going to take a break..."
                        exit 0

        fi
done
else
        RUN=false
        echo "CopyCat: Oh.. But we were having so much fun!"
        exit 0
exit 0
```

Comment: Some advice for next time: Include your source code in the question (questions on this site can stick around and be useful for years, and depending on pastebin.com is not a good idea; it's also less convenient). And try to trim your code down to a smaller example that still reproduces the problem; for example, you could have deleted the `echo`s and the `tease` function. Recommended reading: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `fi` to match the `if` on line 57.

Indenting your code properly would make it easier to find errors like this.

(Incidentally, it's probably not a good idea to install experimental scripts in `/usr/bin`, which is for system binaries. Install in some other directory in your `$PATH`, perhaps `$HOME/bin` -- or just put them in your current directory and run them by typing `./script-name`.)

Comment: Thanks, @keith-thomson . I did the same thing when I first started Java :P